# passing variable value to a label angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to angularjs. i am stuck in an issue and couldnot find a solution. 
i have a table

[Table like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlniG.png)
and if i click on Edit button a modal popups
 [modal like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1YWt.png)

i want to assign menu name and language values from row(from which i click edit button) in table  to labels in modal. i have tried following solution but its not working.

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="VDNApp">
<div class="table-responsive" ng-controller="VDNCtrl">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th  style="visibility:hidden;  width:0%;">#</th>
                <th>Menu Name</th>
                <th>VDN Number</th>
                <th>VDN Name</th>
                <th>Language</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in responseData">
                <td style="visibility:hidden; width:0%;" >{{x.id}}</td>
                <td>{{x.NameEn}}</td>
                <td>{{x.vdnnum}}</td>
                <td>{{x.vdnname}}</td>
                <td>{{x.language}}</td>
                <td><button type="button" ng-click="editVDN(x)"  class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#VDNModal" style="padding:5px 10px !important; font-size:14px !important;">Edit</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="VDNModal" role="dialog" ng-controller="VDNCtrl">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" style="font-weight:bold;">Edit VDN Mapping</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div  >
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" style="font-size:14px;">Menu Name: </label>
                    <label style="font-size:14px; border-color:gray;"  >{{VDNNameValue}}</label>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div  >
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" style="font-size:14px;">VDN Language: </label>
                    <label style="font-size:14px;"> {{VDNlang}}</label>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div>
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" style="font-size:14px;">VDN Number </label>
                    <select  ng-model="selectedOption" ng-options="option.vdnname + ' ('+option.vdnnum + ')' for option in responseData track by option.id" class="form-control selcls" style="width:300px;">
                        <option value="" disabled selected >--Select--</option>
                    </select>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**AngularJS**

```
 var app = angular.module('VDNApp', []);
app.controller('VDNCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://localhost:26413/api/MenuVDN/GetVDNMapping")
.then(function(response) {
    $scope.responseData = response.data.Table;
   // console.log($scope.responseData);
});
    $scope.VDNNameValue = "val";
    $scope.VDNlang = "lang";
    $scope.editVDN = function (obj) {
        $scope.VDNNameValue =  obj.vdnname;
        $scope.VDNlang = obj.language;
        console.log($scope.VDNNameValue, $scope.VDNlang);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined 2 different scopes of VDNCtrl controller. So changing anything in first ng-controller scope won't change anything on second ng-controller scope.

Make sure to use either one controller for both(same scope in one element root) or else create a different controller and set the $scope of new controller by passing the data from first controller

```js
var app = angular.module('VDNApp', []);
app.controller('VDNCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.responseData = [{
    id: 1,
    NameEn: "test",
    vdnnum: "1",
    vdnname: "one",
    language: "en"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    NameEn: "test",
    vdnnum: "1",
    vdnname: "two",
    language: "en"
  }, {
    id: 3,
    NameEn: "test",
    vdnnum: "1",
    vdnname: "three",
    language: "en"
  }];

  $scope.VDNNameValue = "val";
  $scope.VDNlang = "lang";
  $scope.editVDN = function(obj) {
    $scope.VDNNameValue = obj.vdnname;
    $scope.VDNlang = obj.language;
    console.log($scope.VDNNameValue, $scope.VDNlang);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="VDNApp">
  <div class="table-responsive" ng-controller="VDNCtrl">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style="visibility:hidden;  width:0%;">#</th>
          <th>Menu Name</th>
          <th>VDN Number</th>
          <th>VDN Name</th>
          <th>Language</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in responseData">
          <td style="visibility:hidden; width:0%;">{{x.id}}</td>
          <td>{{x.NameEn}}</td>
          <td>{{x.vdnnum}}</td>
          <td>{{x.vdnname}}</td>
          <td>{{x.language}}</td>
          <td><button type="button" ng-click="editVDN(x)" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#VDNModal" style="padding:5px 10px !important; font-size:14px !important;">Edit</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <div class="modal fade" id="VDNModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" style="font-weight:bold;">Edit VDN Mapping</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div>
              <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" style="font-size:14px;">Menu Name: </label>
              <label style="font-size:14px; border-color:gray;">{{VDNNameValue}}</label>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div>
              <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" style="font-size:14px;">VDN Language: </label>
              <label style="font-size:14px;"> {{VDNlang}}</label>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div>
              <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" style="font-size:14px;">VDN Number </label>
              <select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-options="option.vdnname + ' ('+option.vdnnum + ')' for option in responseData track by option.id" class="form-control selcls" style="width:300px;">
                        <option value="" disabled selected >--Select--</option>
                    </select>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks @ashvin777. it does make scene. i alerted a message and it appeared two times which means i have two different scope.